# Trying to get Bridged Networking mode in VMWare Player - Fedora Host

Tags: linux, vmware, fedora

I'm fairly new to Linux, having played with it for a while back in 2002-2003. I recently set up Fedora 21 on a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga, and so far so good. I'm having issues with VMware Player.

I have a Windows 7 guest that needs to be bridged mode, not NAT mode for certain applications I use. When I try to turn on bridged mode, I get the following error:

```
The network bridge on device /dev/vmnet0 is not running.
The virtual machine will not be able to communicate with the host or with other machines on your network.
Failed to connect virtual device Ethernet0.
```

I tried the answer on [this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/131340/bridged-virtual-interface-is-not-available-or-visible-to-ifconfig) without any success. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Remember that you can only bridge to _wired_ interfaces, not to _wireless_ ones.